# Internal Microphone not working on HP mini

Tags: hp, microphone

The internal microphone on my hp mini 1001TU does not work with sound recorder or skype.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Hi Mitch, im using 12.04 LTS 32 bit

Comment: I did a clean install formatted the hard drive. I am not running dual boot, just ubuntu 12.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

Go to sound settings.

If you are using **Unity**, then type Sound in Dash.
If you are using an Older Version, then Select it from your Menu.

Select the `Input` Tab.

Under *Record Sound from*, select Internal Microphone.

It's settings will be shown on the right.

Make sure that Mute is **not** selected.

Hopefully, your Microphone should work fine now.

Comment: yes tried this, still no luck. I installed pulse audio volume control as well and did changes in that and still no luck

Comment: Is Ubuntu the only OS? If your dual-booting, make sure your microphone is working in the other OS.

Comment: In the solution I gave above, under the mute checkbox, you should have an entry, saying something similar to "Adjust Volume". When you speak in your Microphone, are the bars getting filled up there?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04LTS is the only OS on my netbook. It was a new clean install, hard drive formatted.

Comment: when i adjust the volume control and speak into the mic, i dont see any of the bars getting filled.

Comment: This most probably means that your Microphone is dead. To confirm one last time, do this. I hope you have a GMail Account. Enable video chat there, and in the settings page, under chat tab, you will be having similar bars, to set the level of volume of your microphone. If the bars don't get filled there also, then it means your microphone is dead and you have to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

To get help, best one on this Alsa sound issue
answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu...ce/alsa-driver
Steps to get help.

1. Register to the launchpad first
2. Login
3. Key in your question in the question box on the left upper conner.
4. give it 1-2 days someone should come in and help.

I found this below method [from here](https://getsatisfaction.com/jolicloud/topics/internal_mic_doesnt_work_on_hp_mini_1000). It's similar to [what I did here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/202049).

> [avinash.sridhar](https://getsatisfaction.com/people/avinashsridhar) November 15, 2009 19:35
>
> > I have a mini HP mini 1030 NR and got my internal mic to work with the
> >     sound recorder as well as skype 2.1 beta.
> >
> > Here's what I did:   Preferences ->Sound -> Change everything to ALSA
> >
> > edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add the follwing 3 lines to
> >     the end of the file
> >
> > ```
> > alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
> > alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
> > options snd-hda-intel model=hp-m4 enable_msi=1
> > ```
> >
> > save and reboot.
> >
> > Once rebooted , log in and click on the Volume Icon,click Volume
> >     Control , click under the Options tab, make both sources "Line" (i
> >     guess this is due to some mislabeling in the drivers ).

He has details tutorial too.
See if that will work for you.
If not, try to ask for help on Launchpad.